# Collapsed partitions and generating functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, generating-functions, partitions

Given $n\in\Bbb{N}$, the number of (unrestricted) [integer partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n$ are given by
$$\sum_{n\geq0}p(n)x^n=\prod_{j\geq1}\frac1{1-x^j}.$$
Define the collapsed partitions of $n$ to be the partitions of $n$ with multiplicities removed. For example, 
if $n=4$ then its partitions are $4, 31, 22, 211, 1111$. The collapsed partitions become $4, 31, 2, 21, 1$.

Denote the sum 
of the $k$-th powers of the collapsed partitions of $n$ by $cp_k(n)$. For example, $cp_1(4)=4+3+1+2+2+1+1=14$. 
The first few values of $cp_1(n)$ are:
$$cp_1(1)=1, cp_1(2)=3, cp_1(3)=7, cp_1(4)=14, cp_1(5)=26.$$

Recall the [Eulerian polynomials](http://oeis.org/wiki/Eulerian_polynomials) of type $A$ defined by
$$\sum_{n\geq0}(n+1)^kx^n=\frac{A_k(x)}{(1-x)^{k+1}}.$$

> Experiments prompt me to ask: is this true?
>   $$\sum_{n\geq0}cp_k(n+1)x^n=\frac{A_k(x)}{(1-x)^{k+1}}\prod_{j\geq1}\frac1{1-x^j}.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to see that
$$cp_k(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n p(n-i)\cdot i^k,$$
where $p(n-i)$ stands for the number of (collapsed) partitions of $n$ that contain $i$ as a part.

Since $i^k$ is the coefficient of $x^{i-1}$ in $\frac{A_k(x)}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$, we conclude that $cp_k(n)$ equals the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in $\frac{A_k(x)}{(1-x)^{k+1}}\cdot \prod_{j\geq 1}\frac{1}{1-x^j}$. QED

Comment: I found the same answer, but 27 minutes after you. My sum ran from $i=1$ to $i=n$, and I simply said (in my deleted answer) that $i$ participates in exactly $p(n-i)$ stripped partitions, so the identity is clear. The notation $A_k(x)$ is irrelevant to the question and the answer.

Comment: @GHfromMO: I've changed summation to start with $i=1$ to avoid confusion. The answer is indeed quite straightforward. I do not quite follow your comment about $A_k(x)$ being irrelevant.

Comment: What I meant is: you can ask the question and answer it without ever mentioning $A_k(x)$. The identity you state is equivalent to the OP's identity.