# Collapsed partitions and ordinary partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, partitions

Adopt the standard notation for integer partitions, writing $\lambda_1^{a_1} \cdots \lambda_k^{a_k}$ as shorthand for the partition $a_1 \lambda_1 + \cdots + a_k \lambda_k$ with parts $\lambda_1 > \cdots > \lambda_k \geq 1$ and multiplicities $a_i \geq 1$.

If $\lambda = \lambda_1^{a_1} \cdots \lambda_k^{a_k} \vdash n$, its *collapsed image* is the partition with multiple occurrences of parts removed, and is denoted by $\underline{\lambda} := \lambda_1 \cdots \lambda_k$. Introduce the set $\underline{\mathcal{P}_n}=\{\,\underline{\lambda}: \,\lambda\vdash n\}$ as well as the all-familiar 
$\mathcal{P}_n=\{\,\lambda: \,\lambda\vdash n\}$

> **QUESTION.** Is this true? If so, is there a combinatorial proof?
>   $$\#\underline{\mathcal{P}_n}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\#\mathcal{P}_j.$$
>   **CORRECTED.**
>   $$\sum_{\underline{\lambda}\in\underline{\mathcal{P}_n}}\text{length}(\underline{\lambda})=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\#\mathcal{P}_j.$$

**Remark.** For a related problem, [see here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309098/collapsed-partitions-and-generating-functions):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result does not seem to be stated correctly. For instance, $\underline{\mathcal{P}_3}=\{ 3,21,1\}$, yet $p(0)+p(1)+p(2)=4$, where $p(n)=\#\mathcal{P}_n$. It is true that $$\sum_{\lambda\in\underline{\mathcal{P_n}}}\ell(\lambda)=p(0)+p(1)+\cdots+ p(n-1),$$ where $\ell(\lambda)$ is the number of parts of $\lambda$. This is equivalent to the case $k=1$ of *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 1, second ed., Exercise 1.80, which has a simple combinatorial proof.

Comment: Ouch. Yes, your correction is true! Thanks.